# Creating Target lines for BAR chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, graph, ssrs-2008, bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a column chart in SSRS and want to display a target line on this column chart.

I tried the setting the target series as range column chart with TopValue and bottom value as target. But the target line was very thin.

I tried with multiplying the target value with 1.008 for Top value and Bottom value as target. But in this case the width of the target line varies across data.

I also set up the border as solid and width 2 point.

Is there a consistent way of getting a thick target line on column charts (i would also like to do the same thing for bar chart)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume here you are attempting to add a single line to the chart to show what value the columns should be aiming for.

Have you attempted to set up another series in the chart that has the 'target value' for every month.  You can then change the format of this series from a Column format to a Line format.

Reordering the sequence of the series in the Chart Data panel will allow this line to always appear layered on top of the Columns.

If you are trying to achieve a different outcome please can you clarify the desired end effect.

Comment: Yup, I am trying by creating another series for target values. The problem is that I am able to see the line but  when target value for few months is less than maximum limit (label) for Yaxis it's is not thick like other target lines (one that is close to the top)

Comment: Another problem that I am encountering is that For actual values I am trying to display the data points (Chart series labels) but sometimes target line (the second graph) hides the labels (as the second graph is the second series). I tried making target as the the first series and actual values as second series, but in this case target line is hidden completely when actual value > target value (since Graph for actual get painted over target line)